# EXCEPTION PROBLEM WHILE RUNNING A FLUTTER APP

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I created the flutter app using `flutter create` and then i enabled the usb-debugging and install via usb in my mobile developers options.
I am on `ubuntu 20.04 LTS`. So when I run `fluttter run` command in the projects folder i get this error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
> build-tools;29.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2
> To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
> Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Using Android SDK: `/home/spy-maker/Android/Sdk`

Tried:

- Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
- Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

> BUILD FAILED in 1s
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done
> 2,017ms Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Add to question please your `flutter doctor` execution result from console

Answer (score 1):

You just have to accept license by running this command

```
yes | sdkmanager --licenses
```

for Linux Use:

```
yes | ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

for Windows Use:

```
%ANDROID_HOME%/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

Note: set "

> %ANDROID_HOME%

as

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

After that check licenses

Flutter:

> flutter doctor --android-licenses

Comment: Hi Arslan 
Thanks for your answer but this did not work in my scenario instead this give me the output like this

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`
and also this 
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
`